# CoreData N:M relationships

Tags: ios, database, core-data

I have many questions about how to make relationships N:M in CoreData.

If I have two entities A and B and have a relationship N:M in the entity relationship model has to generate a new table C that will contain the unique id of tables A and B.

Example for the entity relationship:

[image]

Now in the database model:

[image]

Considering the previous example as would be done by core data?

[image]

Or:

[image]

The truth is I'm really lost with that of relations in Core Data, any help will be welcome.

Sorry for my English but not very good.

Comment: Your question is not clearly. Tel me what you need exactly.

Comment: First scheme is correct. You can create many-to-many relationships in CoreData in Xcode. Don't need to create association entity.

Comment: But as seen in the second scheme I have an attribute of the relationship "time". How could I do that in CoreData?

Comment: Ganapathy - What I need is to know how to create tables with relationships N: M in CoreData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is that you have to use "join tables" even in Core Data if you are storing additional information. You do not have to keep track of foreign keys, as this is covered by the relationship.

Typically, standard DB "join tables" have ugly names such as "tableA_tableB". You should strive to find a suitable name to make the concept clear. For example:

`Car <<--->> Person`
becomes
`Car <--->> Rental <<---> Person`

Now in entity Rental you can add more information, such as the time. So, for example, if you want to find all persons that rented a car before a certain date (stored as NSDate in the Rental entity), your predicate would be something like this:

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY rentals.time < %@", cutoffTime]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. Now would have on the table NSSet A and B and Table C two NSManagedObject but now the query to get me all data in B as would be done? The query you make a B or a C?

Comment: Sorry, C has 1 object to and an object b but the question is the same. The query to get me all data in B as would be done? The query you make a B or a C?

Comment: I do not understand linguistically. In terms of rental cars, what would be the natural language query?

Comment: Imagine that the table "Rental" has a time field. The query would " tell me all the people who have rented a car ordered by the "time" of the table "Rental" ". More or less this is the query.

Comment: I added the predicate to my answer.